# MS Access and SQL: how to sum the output of 10+ queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

**Added error message**

I have 19 queries that each calculate a value. I now want to add all these values together.

This is the huge query

```
SELECT qryNewAluminumMaterialCostPerUnit.NewAluminumMaterialCost + qryNewChromeMaterialCostPerUnit.NewChromeMaterialCost + qryNewCobaltMaterialCostPerUnit.NewCobaltMaterialCost + qryNewCopperMaterialCostPerUnit.NewCopperMaterialCost + qryNewCRSBenchmarkerEofMSMaterialCostPerUnit.NewCRSBenchmarkerEofMSMaterialCost + qryNewCrudeOilMaterialCostPerUnit.NewCrudeOilMaterialCost + qryNewIronScrap1ChicagoBushMaterialCostPerUnit.NewIronScrap1ChicagoBushMaterialCost + qryNewMWAluminumMaterialCostPerUnit.NewMWAluminumMaterialCost + qryNewNaturalGasMaterialCostPerUnit.NewNaturalGasMaterialCost + qryNewNickelMaterialCostPerUnit.NewNickelMaterialCost + qryNewOilMaterialCostPerUnit.NewOilMaterialCost + qryNewOtherMaterialCostPerUnit.NewOtherMaterialCost + qryNewPlastic1MaterialCostPerUnit.NewPlastic1MaterialCost + qryNewPlastic2MaterialCostPerUnit.NewPlastic2MaterialCost + qryNewPlastic3MaterialCostPerUnit.NewPlastic3MaterialCost + qryNewSilverMaterialCostPerUnit.NewSilverMaterialCost + qryNewTheoretical301MaterialCostPerUnit.NewTheoretical301MaterialCost + qryNewTheoretical304MaterialCostPerUnit.NewTheoretical304MaterialCost + qryNewZincMaterialCostPerUnit.NewZincMaterialCost
FROM qryNewAluminumMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewChromeMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewCobaltMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewCopperMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewCRSBenchmarkerEofMSMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewCrudeOilMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewIronScrap1ChicagoBushMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewMWAluminumMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewNaturalGasMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewNickelMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewOilMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewOtherMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewPlastic1MaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewPlastic2MaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewPlastic3MaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewSilverMaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewTheoretical301MaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewTheoretical304MaterialCostPerUnit, qryNewZincMaterialCostPerUnit;
```

I get the error that there isn't enough room. Is there a more simple way to add all queries' output than the above format?

NOte: all queries return one single record, one single value.

Comment: Well that error message is pretty straightforward. Your single expression in the SELECT clause is 1173 characters. But maybe it works in SQL view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT q1 + q2 + q3 + .... q19
FROM q1, q2, q3, ... q19
```

If each query returns a single record, then this should work fine. If it doesn't then you are getting a [Cartesian product](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) of all the tables... which fill up ram in a heart beat. If your queries have many records and many fields, then this doesn't even make sense to begin with.

Perhaps Join your queries, or Union your result sets and then sum. Something like:

```
   SELECT sum(f1) 
   FROM
       (
            SELECT f1 FROM q1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT f1 FROM q2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT f1 FROM q3
       )as unionSubQuery
```

Comment: I uploaded the actual code so you can see. I tried the first code again after closing and opening access, and oddly enough, it works this time. I wanted to show the error I got. In other words, the first code I used and the first code you suggested works.

Comment: I'm wondering if access is doing some oddball execution plan that causes a very large intermediate cartesian result set due to the join. My guess is that opening and closing cleared enough ram that the oddball execution path was able to squeek through. It'd be interesting to watch the ram usage during execution through ProcessXP or similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the output columns of each query. Best use a short alias in each of the queries. E.g.

```
SELECT q1.Val1 + q2.Val2 + q3.Val3 + .... q19.Val19
FROM q1, q2, q3, ... q19
```

If each query returns exactly one row, this should work in principle.

Wait... does "there isn't enough room" mean that Access runs out of (temporary) disk space?

If yes, the easiest way might be to write a VBA function that loops over the queries, reads each value and adds them up. This way Access doesn't have to run all queries at once.

Comment: Each query returns one row, so the code you offered is correct too.

Comment: But you need the column names. :)  Note that the error may return when you run the query later, perhaps after running other stuff in Access before it. What was the exact error message?

Comment: I added the error message. I did include the column name.